# Subdomain locations on server

Tags: apache

I have had a look to see if this has been answered but to no avail.
Perhaps is so obvious that it doesn't need answering?

I have made a subdomains folder on my server where I want to keep all my subdomains in.
Does this folder have to be in the public_html folder or can I have this folder on the root (same level as the public_html folder)?
I know this works as I have tried it, but is this good practice?

The reason I ask is because the subdomains can be access like a subfolder

e.g. www.mywebsite.com/subdomains/aNewSubdomain

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can configure your web server freely, you can put the folder anywhere you like; actually, it is good *not* to have it in the `public_html` folder because that way, all subdomains would be accessible as sub folders of the main domain.